# How to use the openie.triple.strict option in StanfordNLP parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp, information-extraction

I am new to NLP and want an example to help me understand how to use the openie.triple.strict option under the openie property of the StanfordNLP parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to the same is:-

Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref, natlog, openie");

props.setProperty("openie.resolve_coref", "false"); //default = true

Thanks [Gabor Angeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1473431/gabor-angeli) for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example command you can set the option to true or false.  The default is true.

```
java -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,mention,natlog,openie -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text -openie.triple.strict false
```

Comment: How can this option be used through the CoreNLP API?

Comment: When you build the pipeline, you will use a Properties object.  Set the "openie.triple.strict" in that Properties object.

Comment: Yes. So I tried something like this:-
Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("annotators",tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie.triple.strict");
Which gives me an error

Comment: You don't add it to the annotators list, it's a separate property.

Comment: I am a beginner.. Could you be more specific when you say it's a separate property? How do I integrate/use the same? @GaborAngeli

Comment: You should have multiple calls to `setProperty`. One to set the annotators (`setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie")`) and others to set options for the annotators (`setProperty("openie.triples.strict", "true")` and so on).